# HTML input pattern validation

Tags: html, validation

```html
<form class="user" action="code_user.php" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Enter Full Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(( )+[a-zA-z]+)*$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter in alphabets only. ')" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
   </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit"name="signup_btn"class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"> Sign Up </button>

</form>
```

In HTML input validation , i have set the pattern of alphebetic only. When testing with numeric input in it , it shows 
[image]

However, if i correct the input into the alphabets ,it will shows invalid again
[image]

I have to refresh the page again to input the correct format only it will not show 
invalid. Is this normal?
This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Enter Full Name</label>
     <input class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(( )+[a-zA-z]+)*$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter in alphabets only. ')" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me. Try adding a code snippet to your question where we could try it.

Comment: Does it show the error immediately? The check is only performed on submission of the form (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

Comment: @BartBarnard yes, it showed the error immediately when i enter a letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't clear your `setCustomValidity()`. If you set a value with `setCustomValidity()` then the field is invalid. Just add such attribute to your input tag:

```
oninput="setCustomValidity('')"
```

Fixed in your code:

```html
<form class="user" action="code_user.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter Full Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+(( )+[a-zA-z]+)*$" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter in alphabets only. ')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit"name="signup_btn"class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block"> Sign Up </button>
</form>
```